# How to consume a restful WCF service in a Windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

I am trying to consume a restful WCF service in a Windows application. Please give me any suggestion. The restful service is consumed in jquery ajax my local url http://localhost:4722/Service1.svc/departments/

Comment: please post what you have tried so far and where you stuck ?

Comment: please tell me the procedure how to consume a wcf restfull service in C# windows application

Comment: were you able to host service with appropriate binding configuration ? and question is only how to consume it ? If yes, use `HttpClient`

Comment: services are consumed in web application. i have question its possible to consume   same services in desktop application or not

Comment: yes. thats why i said you can use httpClient

Comment: please give me any example or code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.5 or higher for you application you can use HttpClient:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{   
    string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:4722/Service1.svc/departments/"));

    //handle response
}
```

Otherwise you can use WebClient:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{   
    string response = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:4722/Service1.svc/departments/");

    //handle response
}
```

Both examples assume the service URL allows a basic GET requests and retrieve the data as a strings. Additional work will need to be done to transform the data into objects. For instance if it is returned as JSON you will need to de-serialzie the JSON vai your preferred JSON library.